# How to update a page dynamically with database information using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm coding my first eCommerce site and in the planning process I've run into a problem. Basically on the product screen the user is given 3 drop down menus for style, color, and finish. Now based on these I want to display the relevant information from the database to display; price and description. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is there a way to dynamically query the database without refreshing the page or using a submit that requires more user interaction?

Comment: yes, there is a way. You can do it by issuing a HTTP request from your Javascript, it is called AJAX. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: seems like you need to learn AJAX ?  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: just go for ajax, apply it on the event of your dropdown selected

Comment: Is it possible to load that information with the page? Sending AJAX requests every time you change some option will make the page appear sluggish. AJAX may be convenient, but it is not always the most clever solution.

Comment: Unless there is a massive amount of options, or the content is truly dynamic (as in it could have changed since the page loaded) I would just use php to dynamically write the javascript code to display the information. AJAX is probably overkill in this case.

Comment: AJAX is something you should learn; but I agree with the last 2 that it is overkill in this scenario.  You can load all different scenarios on page load and use JavaScript onSelect functions to change between different colors, prices, and descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax ajax can load the info you want.

Here is an exmaple of what you want with selection box, with a tutorial.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

but then you need to replace the sql query with the query you need so it sends back the information of the product with the right style, color and finish.